How can / should I report an apparent bug in ansi-term handling embedded vim processes?
As a regular vi user, I have been using Emacs in Evil mode and ansi-term to use Emacs as a terminal and editor that will display proportional fonts as proportional fonts.
I am reaching 99% compatibility with ingrained vi usage skills in Evil mode. However, when I pull up an ansi-term window and invoke vim, whether locally or on a server I ssh into, Emacs ansi-term gets confused about what line it is on, and often seems to think it is on one line higher or lower than it actually indicates. (I have not had this difficulty with vim locally or remotely from gnome-terminal, which is why I am guessing it to be a defect in Emacs ansi-term.)
Is this a defect in Emacs as regards ansi-term? If so, what is the followup? If I should file a defect report, where should I be filing it?

If you think you've found an Emacs bug then use M-x report-emacs-bug to report it. That will open a buffer where you describe the bug. You then use C-c C-c to send that description to Emacs by email. This is all described in the buffer where you describe the bug.
See the Emacs manual (C-h r), node Reporting Bugs.

My laptop is not presently configured to use email, and I searched briefly and did not see how to manually send an email or report it at a web address. Is there any way that I can send an email from my mailer, or from a web interface? Thanks,

When you say "from my mailer" do you mean a mail client, such as Outlook? If so, then just follow the Emacs prompt; it will ask you whether to use your mail client - say yes. Then, in your client, paste the text that Emacs copied for you and send the mail.

Thank you. What recipient email address should I use?

It will automatically provide the recipient. But if you read the doc I cited it tells you that the recipient is bug-gnu-emacs@gnu.org.
